# GUI written in python (with PyQT/PySide2) does not launch

Tags: terminal, python, ui

I just updated to Big Sur 11.2.1 and wanted to launch a python script that I wrote in a GUI with `PySide2`. When I launch the script, the terminals seems to be busy with the app:

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

[image: screenshot3]

However nothing more happens: the GUI doe not launch, there is no error message. and I have to kill manually the app. Here is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Import PySide classes
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

# Create a Qt application
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
# Create a Label and show it
label = QLabel("Hello World")
label.show()
# Enter Qt application main loop
app.exec_()
sys.exit()
```

If a run the a script containing only `print("hello")` from the terminal, this works

Moreover in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk access, the app `iTerm.app` is selected (so `iTerm.app` should have permiession)

Answer (score -1):

I just found the answer [in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64833558/apps-not-popping-up-on-macos-big-sur-11-0-1#_=). For some weird reason, one has to add the following piece of code at the beginning of the script.

```
import os
os.environ['QT_MAC_WANTS_LAYER'] = '1'
```

And that worked for me

Comment: That is coincidence qt does not use t app and mathplotlib is a different thing. Look at examples in the qt documentation